# changing facebook login button type

Tags: facebook

Currently I have the following button, when using facebook javascript:

[image]

and I want to get this one:

[image]

What should I change?

Currently the way I did this is using the following code:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
      <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
      <script>
         FB.init({ 
            appId:'YOUR_APP_ID', cookie:true, 
            status:true, xfbml:true 
         });
      </script>
      <fb:login-button>Login with Facebook</fb:login-button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With [Facebook PHP-sdk](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk) you can replace it with any button or icon

```
<?php if ($me) { ?>
  <a href="<?php echo $logoutUrl; ?>"><img src="logout-image.png"></a>
<?php } else { ?>
  <a href="<?php echo $loginUrl; ?>"><img src="login-image.png"></a>
<?php } ?>
```

Or http://fbrell.com/xfbml/fb:login-button

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the text "Login With Facebook" with "Connect With Facebook" in your login button code. Or use the below code.

```
<div id="fb-root">
        </div>
        <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js">
        </script>
        <fb:login-button>Connect with Facebook</fb:login-button>
        <script>
          FB.init({
            appId: '123456',
            cookie: true,
            status: true,
            xfbml: true
          });

        </script>
```

Comment: Actually that's going to render regular login button: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/login/ , not the one that he wants.

Comment: @Equinox, can you please elaborate what you want to do (may be how you got that "Login With Facebook" Button). If you don't mind, please read this http://tinyurl.com/so-hints before editing your question.

Comment: Then you should get what you want by replacing "Login with Facebook" by "Connect With Facebook" in the last line of your code. Isn't that you want?

Answer (score 0):

For that particular button, you will have to include the image yourself and bind the functionality with one of the SDKs available:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/sdks/

I personally prefer using the [JS SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/) to open the login prompt.

You can use [regular login button](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/login/), which is the approach that @MNVR has described in his answer.